# angular js set form to dirty programmatically

Tags: angularjs

my check boxes run a function with operates several tasks to manipulate the model programmatically and this seems to not allow the form to become dirty.

on the basis my form is named "testForm" how would I include a reference in my existing function to set the form to be dirty when that checkbox calls it on click?

do I need to reference the forms name or is it a case of setting the model to be dirty such as

```
$scope.$dirty = true;
```

Comment: Usually you should be able to access the FormController with your $scope, e.g. $scope.form.$dirty

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$form.$setDirty();     
$form.email.$dirty = true;
```

**Here, $form = form.

email = field name.**

Comment: hi, I tried this but still had no luck but instead used: $scope.testForm.$setDirty(); that now allows my form to be dirty. Thanks

Comment: This way if i edit the one row email field value then dirty flag set all the rows, how to set the dirty flag only for the edited row. instead of all the rows.